# What do the values after `execute fetch from` mean in postgresql query logs?

Tags: postgresql, logs

We've turned on some slow query logging on a postgres 9.1 cluster and see
the following in the logs::

```
2016-08-08 13:05:51 AEST LOG:  duration: 24126.105 ms  execute fetch from S_26/C_775: SELECT ...(query continues)
```

What does the S_26/C_775 bit mean? Can I use this to find which client submitted the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S_26` is a statement name and `C_775` a portal name in the extended-query protocol.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-overview.html

> In the extended-query protocol, execution of SQL commands is divided
>   into multiple steps. The state retained between steps is represented
>   by two types of objects: prepared statements and portals. A prepared
>   statement represents the result of parsing and semantic analysis of a
>   textual query string. A prepared statement is not in itself ready to
>   execute, because it might lack specific values for parameters. A
>   portal represents a ready-to-execute or already-partially-executed
>   statement, with any missing parameter values filled in. (For SELECT
>   statements, a portal is equivalent to an open cursor, but we choose to
>   use a different term since cursors don't handle non-SELECT
>   statements.)

To find the query bound to this statement, look upper in the log for the corresponding `bind` entry.

If it doesn't exist, you might have to increase the logging level to `DEBUG2` through `log_min_error_statement`, or set `log_min_duration_statement` to 0.